# Spring Boot Test, Transactions and seeding db with data before test

Tags: spring-boot, transactions, spring-jdbc, spring-test, spring-transactions

After configuring Transaction propagation in my Spring Boot application, the tests I had created are failing and I am unable to make them pass again. I am using:

- Spring Boot 3.1.3
- Spring Data JDBC
- Ktorm 3.6.0 (Kotlin ORM based on JDBC)

For testing purposes, I have created `BaseTestConfiguaration` class that:

- is a parent class for all test classes,
- contains utility functions for inserting sample data to the database,
- imports `TestFoodWarehouseApplication` class that defines `PostgreSQLContainer` bean (a container instance powered by TestContainers).

```kotlin
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@Import(TestFoodWarehouseApplication::class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class BaseTestConfiguration(@Autowired protected val db: Database) {
  protected fun seedDbWithCategories() { /* Inserts a couple of categories to DB */ }
  protected fun truncateCategories() { /* Truncates categories table */ } 
}
```

### The problem

Now coming to the actual test class, the problem arises when I try to execute `seedDbWithCategories()` inside a test method (see last test method). The function executes normally and a proper query is generated, but the database stays **empty**. The database however is populated normally when `seedDbWithCategories()` is called in a method annotated with `@BeforeTransaction` (see the first nested test class).

```kotlin
@Transactional
class CategoriesControllerTest(@Autowired db: Database) : BaseTestConfiguration(db) {

  @Nested
  @TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
  inner class DeleteCategoryCases {
    @BeforeTransaction
    fun setup() = seedDbWithCategories()

    @AfterTransaction
    fun cleanup() = truncateCategories()

    @Test
    fun `should remove category and its children`() { 
      /* REST Assured assertions - everything OK here */
    }    
  }

  @Nested
  @TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
  inner class GetParentCategoriesCases {
    @Test
    fun `when no categories exists, should return empty array`() {
      /* REST Assured assertions - everything OK as db should be empty now */
    }

    @Test
    fun `should return categories without parents`() {
      seedDbWithCategories()
      
      /* REST Assured assertions - NOT OK, the db is empty, but should contain my sample data */

      truncateCategories()
    }
}
```

### The Question

Is it possible in any way to make `seedDbWithCategories()` work in both cases?

#### Efforts until now

What I expect is of course that my database is seeded with sample data correctly and then truncated after the test.

So far I have tried:

1. wrapping the call of `seedDbWithCategories()` in `TestTransaction.start()/.end()`
2. wrapping the body of `seedDbWithCategories()` in `TestTransaction.start()/.end()`
3. Annotating `seedDbWithCategories()` with `@Transactional` with propagation set to Propagation.NESTED/REQUIRES_NEW/REQUIRED
4. Annotating the method like before, but also with `@Commit`
5. Doing steps from 3. and 4. the same for the entire class
6. Various combination of previous steps altogether

Previous attempts failed for different reasons:

1. TransactionContext is not active
2. Cannot start a new transaction without ending the existing transaction first

What I am really trying to avoid, is rewriting about 50 tests, that use calls like `seedDbWithCategories()` inside a test method or wrapping them in a `@Nested` class with just one test method inside.

Any help is appreciated and thank you for answers in advance.